# Add total pages to the Django Rest Framework response when using pagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pagination

At the Django Rest Framework Documentation you can add pagination according to the document at this link:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

and the response will look like:

```
HTTP 200 OK
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

How can I add "total_pages" to the response?

```
HTTP 200 OK
{
    "count": 1023
 ==>"total_pages": 12
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=5",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?page=3",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

I looked into the DRF code and saw the PageNumberPagination class has a "num_pages" property.  But I'm not sure how to call it in the StandardResultsSetPagination class.

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0323d6f8955f987771269506ca5da461e2e7a248/rest_framework/pagination.py

Comment: @xyres -- highly likely, but I'll have to look at it tomorrow and report back.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes @xyres, thanks!